# How does etherscan get such data?

Tags: web3js, etherscan, contract-invocation

I need to select special transactions like these: 
[image]
That is, a sale transaction, with a certain price (0 ether, as here). As a result of the work carried out, I can determine which nft from which contract were transferred to whom and by whom. But I still don't understand how etherscan determines that this is a Sale action and finds out the price? Can I do this using the web3 api?
[Transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xee05bb571ffcdb644934620ff00683c3f5ead46b73a0308dbb802d6b99fe438a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to add on to the previous answer for your specific case.

Since you are looking for Sales on opensea, You will use `web3.eth.getTransaction()` and loop through the logs array that is returned for the topics array of each log.

If the "0x9d9af8e38d66c62e2c12f0225249fd9d721c54b83f48d9352c97c6cacdcb6f31" topic is included in the topics array, then that means it is a sale on opensea seaport contract. You can find this by looking through the seaport contract on etherscan.

To find the value in wei of the transaction you can use `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt()`

to answer your comment, "0x9d9af8e38d66c62e2c12f0225249fd9d721c54b83f48d9352c97c6cacdcb6f31"
is a topic of the OrderFulfilled event that is emitted by the opensea seaport contract when an order is completed. Here is the format of this event from the contract code.

```
/*
 *  Memory layout in _prepareBasicFulfillmentFromCalldata of
 *  data for OrderFulfilled
 *
 *   event OrderFulfilled(
 *     bytes32 orderHash,
 *     address indexed offerer,
 *     address indexed zone,
 *     address fulfiller,
 *     SpentItem[] offer,
 *       > (itemType, token, id, amount)
 *     ReceivedItem[] consideration
 *       > (itemType, token, id, amount, recipient)
 *   )
 *
 *  - 0x00: orderHash
 *  - 0x20: fulfiller
 *  - 0x40: offer offset (0x80)
 *  - 0x60: consideration offset (0x120)
 *  - 0x80: offer.length (1)
 *  - 0xa0: offerItemType
 *  - 0xc0: offerToken
 *  - 0xe0: offerIdentifier
 *  - 0x100: offerAmount
 *  - 0x120: consideration.length (1 + additionalRecipients.length)
 *  - 0x140: considerationItemType
 *  - 0x160: considerationToken
 *  - 0x180: considerationIdentifier
 *  - 0x1a0: considerationAmount
 *  - 0x1c0: considerationRecipient
 *  - ...
 */
```

Comment: What does "0x9d9af8e38d66c62e2c12f0225249fd9d721c54b83f48d9352c97c6cacdcb6f31" represent?

Comment: I'll update my answer so I can add images

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

There are a number of ways ERC20/ERC721 differ.

API’s/node providers allow filtering dependant on certain aspects of transaction’s data to deduce what happened in that transaction. This can be done in a multitude of ways, depending on what precisely you’re looking to achieve.

In your case, look for the `transfer` signature (first 4 bytes of tx.signature yields this) in transaction logs matching ERC721 (ERC20 topics.length == 3, ERC721 topics.length == 4). You can then deduce which are transactions of interest by inspecting the value passed in the transaction via `web3.eth.getTransaction()`.

This is essentially what etherscan does in certain places to display a practical user interface, but we can use things like Alchemy or Infura to achieve the same (likely more tailored) thing.